# How to change the height of a (multi)row in tabular with math

Tags: math-mode, tables, spacing, multirow

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lcccl}
  \textbf{Irland}       &    -   &   -    &     x    &   $ FE_{UN}(t) - FE_{UN}(t=2003)$     \\ \hline
  \textbf{Portugal} &   x  &   x &    x  &    \multirow{2}{*}{$ FE_{UN}(t) - \displaystyle{ \frac{1}{2}\cdot\sum_{u=t-2}^{t-1} FE_{UN}(u)}$}    \\ 
  \textbf{Spanien}  &           x  & x   &     x     &  \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which simply doesn't look good. 
[image: MWE]

How can I fix this?!

Comment: By the way... Can anyone give me a tip, how to make pretty images without much effort? This clearly doesn't look good.

Comment: on Mac OS X, what I usually do is to produce a pdf (either via dvips or via pdftex) then in Reader I select the "photographic" tool, I select the area of interest, then I go to Preview.app, choose "create from clipboard", and finally I do an "export as PNG". In my experience this produces lightweight images with good quality. I have also used convert from ImageMagick to convert a pdf to png (and for the pdf, after having paid attention to not have page numbers, I used pdfcrop to trim white spaces). Or one can use dvips with -E option, and then convert. I forgot: dvipng with the -Ttight option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lcccl}
  \textbf{Ireland}       &    -   &   -    &     x    &   $ FE_{UN}(t) - FE_{UN}(t=2003)$     \\ \hline
  \textbf{Portugal}\bigstrut &   x  &   x &    x  &    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{$ FE_{UN}(t) - \displaystyle{ \frac{1}{2}\cdot\sum_{u=t-2}^{t-1} FE_{UN}(u)}$}    \\ 
  \textbf{Spanien}\bigstrut  &           x  & x   &     x     &  \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

gives [image: table corrected]

Comment: @meep.meep: I apologize for having changed Irland into Ireland: I just hadn't noticed Spanien which seems to demonstrate the language is German. Well, I leave this at it stands, as one can not be perfect and it is better to make small silly mistakes than big silly ones. Hopefully my counter of mistakes will thus increase by one and avoid me a big one in the future.

Comment: Thanks, but is just a code ample anyway... Really no need to apologize for being thoughtfull :) :)